# how to add json file in ActionRequestHandler safari extinction

Tags: ios, objective-c, safari, xcode7.3

I am develop a add blocker app, so i want to add json file in my ActionRequestHandler class from document directory. In ActionRequestHandler class already have code that add blockerList.json which is in main bundle 
actually main problem is this if i edit in blockerList.json then its not editable because of permission because this file is in main bundle so aap don't provide on editing in any file.So i generate a new file in document directory which is editable but i cant add it in safari extention. here is my code

```
- (void)beginRequestWithExtensionContext:(NSExtensionContext *)context {
NSItemProvider *attachment;
NSString *contentOfURL;
NSString *documentsFilePath = [self grabFilePath:@"Block.json"];
NSURL *documentsURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:documentsFilePath];
if ([documentsFilePath length] != 0) {

    NSError *error;
   // NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:APP_DEFAULT_BLOCKS_URL];//[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:APP_DEFAULT_BLOCKS_URL]
    contentOfURL = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:documentsURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    if (error)
    NSLog(@"Error reading remote json file: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}

if (contentOfURL != (id)[NSNull null] && contentOfURL.length != 0) {
    attachment = [[NSItemProvider alloc] initWithItem:contentOfURL typeIdentifier:@"public.json"];
} else {
    NSLog(@"URL not defined or accessible - using local JSON");
    attachment = [[NSItemProvider alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"blockerList" withExtension:@"json"]];
}

NSExtensionItem *item = [[NSExtensionItem alloc] init];
item.attachments = @[attachment];

[context completeRequestReturningItems:@[item] completionHandler:nil];

}
- (NSString *)grabFilePath:(NSString *)fileName {

NSString *filePath = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Documents/%@",     fileName];
NSString *documentsFilePath =    [NSHomeDirectory()stringByAppendingPathComponent:filePath];

return documentsFilePath;
}
```